# Find by field Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I need to get a register by a field different to ID, an int and unique fild named "rut_num", but I'm getting an error in the repository query:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="paciente")
public class Paciente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="rut_num")
    private int rut_num;

    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="a_pat")
    private String a_pat;

    @Column(name="a_mat")
    private String a_mat;

    //getters and setters
```

Repository:

```
@Repository("pacienteRepository")
public interface PacienteJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Paciente, Serializable> {

    @Query("SELECT nombre FROM paciente WHERE rut_num= :rut_num")
    Future<String> findByRut(@Param("rut_num") int rut_num);
}
```

Service and Impl:

```
public interface PacienteService {

    public abstract Paciente findByRut(int rut_num);
}

@Service("pacienteServiceImpl")
public class PacienteServiceImpl implements PacienteService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pacienteRepository")
    private PacienteJpaRepository pacienteRepository;

    @Override
    public Paciente findByRut(int rut_num) {
        return (Paciente) pacienteRepository.findByRut(rut_num);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PacienteController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pacienteServiceImpl")
    private PacienteService pacienteService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/paciente/{rut_num}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> findByRut(@PathVariable("rut_num") int rut_num){
        Paciente paciente = pacienteService.findByRut(rut_num);
        if (paciente == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Paciente>(paciente, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Error in console:

> Error creating bean with name 'pacienteServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'pacienteRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'pacienteRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   java.util.concurrent.Future
>   com.calendar.repository.PacienteJpaRepository.findByRut(int)!

Comment: Your service method reads `(Paciente) pacienteRepository.findByRut(rut_num)`, while your repository returns `Future<String>`. Why would a `Future` be castable to your custom type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the name of your entity you are refearing to in your query is "Paciente" not "paciente", so changing

```
@Query("SELECT nombre FROM paciente WHERE rut_num= :rut_num")
Future<String> findByRut(@Param("rut_num") int rut_num);
```

To

```
@Query("SELECT nombre FROM Paciente WHERE rut_num= :rut_num")
Future<String> findByRut(@Param("rut_num") int rut_num);
```

Should works

Hope it helps